# How does the following algorithm have a time complexity of 0(n^2)

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

So I'm a beginner learning time complexity and if someone can explain how:

```
For (i := 0; i < n; i = i + 1)
    For (j := i; j < n; j = j + 1)
```

has a time complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, I understand that it is **n** work done **n** times, but how? Also if you could tell me what `:=` means, that would be great.

Comment: If `:=` means the assignment operator, then your text is inconsistent in that I would expect `i = i+1` to be `i := i+1`.

Comment: Let's count how many iteration inner loop has: n, n-1, n-2, n-3, ... 2, 1. It's Arithmetic progression =, Sum of it is  about (n^2)/2 + (some n). ignoring constants, it's O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

Let's change the code a little bit:

```
x = 0
For (i := 0; i < n; i = i + 1)      //it says: let i be 1, 2, ..., until n - 1
    For (j := i; j < n; j = j + 1)  //it says: let j be i, i+1, ..., until n - 1
        x = x + 1
```

What will the value of `x` be?

It's easy to count how many times the second `For` will run.

It starts from 0 to n-1, then 1 to n-1, 2 to n-1, ..., n-1 to n-1. So it means, in operations:

```
0  1  2 ... (n-1) = (n-1) - 0 + 1 operations =    n    operations
1  2  ..... (n-1) = (n-1) - 1 + 1 operations = (n - 1) operations
2  ........ (n-1) = (n-1) - 2 + 1 operations = (n - 2) operations
        .
        .
        .
      (n-1)                                  =    1    operation 
                                               ___________________
                                              (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n) 
                                               = (n + 1) * (n / 2) 
                                               =     (n² + n)/2  operations
```

We can see that these `For` totalize `(n² + n)/2` operations, so `x = (n² + n)/2`.

In complexity analysis, we follow some rules. I'll describe the ones which are useful in this case:

`1` **Remove multiplicative constants**:

```
O((n² + n)/2) = O(0.5 * (n² + n)) = O(n² + n)
```

The theory behind it is that when `n` goes to infinite, these constants won't make a difference in the behaviour of the function.

`2` **Remove terms with lower power grade**:

```
O(n² + n) = O(n²)
```

The theory behind it is that the variable with the biggest power grade (`n²` in this case) rules the behaviour of the function over the ones with lowest grade.

This is why we can state that the complexity of these nested loops is O(n²).